# How to horizontally centre form in span with bootstrap 2.3.2?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code...

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span6">
    <h2>Some Text</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="span6">
    <form class="form-inline pull-right">
      <input type="text" class="input-large">
      <button type="submit" class="btn">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

...but the search form doesn't align with the h2 tag. Do I need to have the form custom styled via css or am I missing out on some default Bootstrap class to fix this?

Thanks so much for taking time to read/answer this query.

[edit]

http://jsfiddle.net/nuB23/

Added jsfiddle

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle to demonstrate the issue in action?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nuB23/

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `pull-right` class on the form.
The other issue is the h2 has extra padding and is a block level. I think what you are really after is this:

```
<div class="nav"> </div>

<div class="container">
    <form class="form-horizontal ">
        <div class="control-group  ">
            <label class="control-label large" for="searchInput">Label text:</label>
            <div class="controls search">
                <div class="input-prepend "> <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-search"></i></span>
                    <input type="text" id="searchInput"  />
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Search</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dbrin/AV654/

Comment: Thanks dbrin but what is the purpose of the empty div with class="nav"?

Comment: Just a placeholder for a possible top menu, its not needed and just pushes the main content down a bit off the top of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this style:

```
[class*="span"], h2 {
    display: inline;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nuB23/2/)**